# Send money using Paypal php rest SDK

Tags: php, laravel-4, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I'm trying to include a donation button into my website.
The idea is to allow users to send money from their account to the admin account.
I used the Paypal REST SDK to send money, but I found that the admin account was charged by the transaction fees which depends on the user's country.

```
                        $payer = new Payer();
                        $payer->setPaymentMethod('paypal');

                        $amount = new Amount();
                        $amount->setCurrency('EUR')
                                ->setTotal($money);

                        $transaction = new Transaction();
                        $transaction->setAmount($amount)

                        ->setDescription('donation');

                        $redirect_urls = new RedirectUrls();
                        $redirect_urls->setReturnUrl(URL::route('funding.status'))

                                ->setCancelUrl(URL::route('funding.status'));


                        $payment = new Payment();
                        $payment->setIntent('Sale')
                                ->setPayer($payer)
                                ->setRedirectUrls($redirect_urls)
                                ->setTransactions(array($transaction));
```

I'm not selling any product.I just want to fund a project.Is there any way to get the received money getting by the admin account? And can I made the transaction fees charged by the user who send the money?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal in REST/Classic API that the receiver will incur the transaction fee.
The model you are looking at is "Adaptive Payments" where you could decide who wants to pay the fee.

[Read](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

Basically in Adaptive Payments, if you would wish that the person [who sends money should pay the fee](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/#id091QF0N0MPF__id092SH0YG0Y4) , you can do so in Adaptive Payments.For instance, you can use a variable called `feesPayer = SENDER` in [Pay API](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/) operation.

**P.S** You will need to create a app at apps.paypal.com to make use of Adaptive Payments Feature in PayPal.

Comment: is there any tutorial of how to use paypal adaptive payments with laravel projects?

Comment: it's ok i found this:https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/ap_chained_payment/php?env=sandbox#credentialsModal