# Send money using PayPal API & PHP

Tags: php, api, paypal

How can I send money using PHP and the PayPal API these days?

I've seen multiple responses from few years ago on Stack and the solutions out there are now deprecated documentation...

Example : [Send money using Paypal php rest SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27354157/send-money-using-paypal-php-rest-sdk) or
[Can I send money with Paypal API to other paypal account? If yes how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48633606/can-i-send-money-with-paypal-api-to-other-paypal-account-if-yes-how)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adaptive Payments is deprecated and cannot be used for any new integrations.

The Payouts API would work. In the live environment the business account sending the payout must be approved for the feature, contact PayPal's general support (not technical support) for that.